# Append new data and update exisitng data in table from inserting another

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, outer-join, isnull

In SQL, I have a table with 3 columns that is refreshed through the day. I want to append "table a" data to "table b". I need to ensure the there are no duplicate rows by date, but also that is the sale_count in creases that the sale count is updated and not put in a a new row.

table a

| date | id | sale_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/20/21 | 1 | 7 |
| 12/20/21 | 2 | 3 |
| 12/21/21 | 2 | 2 |

table b pre-update

| date | id | sale_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/20/21 | 1 | 5 |
| 12/20/21 | 2 | 3 |

table b post update

| date | id | sale_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/20/21 | 1 | 7 |
| 12/20/21 | 2 | 3 |
| 12/21/21 | 2 | 2 |

code I have so far that is still allowing duplicate rows

```
INSERT INTO tableB
SELECT
  a.[date]
  ,a.id
  ,a.sale_count
FROM tableA a
Left outer join tableB b
on a.[date] = b.[date] 
and a.id = b.id
and a.sale_count = b.sale_count
where b.[date] IS NULL
AND b.sale_count is NULL
```

Comment: You want to insert some rows and update others. That's a [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @SOS right, if the sales count increases for that id on that given date, a new row is not inserted but the sales_count is updated

Comment: @ShayD  - The join on `sale_count` is what's allowing the dupes. It's creating a new record any time the count changes, instead of when the `id` and `date` are missing. The modern way is to use MERGE as MatBailie suggested. The old style way is to first run an UPDATE on what's changed, i.e. same id and date. Then INSERT non-existing records. That's what a MERGE does, but with a different syntax.  I'd recommend using MERGE in the actual code, but to illustrate the general concept http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/82ef2a/12